# Copiar texto do Wikipédia em Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automatização

Olá, eu queria saber como eu posso copiar o texto de uma página no wikipédia, podendo ser apenas o primeiro parágrafo sobre o assunto

Aqui está o que eu já fiz:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
print('Pesquise aqui o que você quiser:') 
var1 = input() 
navegador = webdriver.Chrome() navegador.get('https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s' %var1)
```

Comment: Em vez de fazer manualmente, uma opção é usar [isso](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode utilizar BeautifulSoup junto com requests para fazer esse trabalho:

O código procura todo o conteúdo da página via URL e retorna ela.
Logo depois ele procura a div "mw-parser-output" e depois retorna o conteúdo html dela.
Por fim, ele lê esse conteúdo e procura a tag <p> retornando seu valor.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = input("Search Wiki: ")

u = requests.get("https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/{}".format(r)).text
v = bs(u, "html.parser")
w = v.find("div", {"class": "mw-parser-output"})

x = bs(w.decode(), "html.parser").find_all("p")[0]
print(x.text)
```

Comment: Valeu mano, era exatamente disso que eu precisava. Tem algum site ou vídeo que mostra mais sobre essa biblioteca do beautiful soup? Gostei dela